# How to merge two GPS coordinates without losing decimals

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, gps, variables, convert

I want to take the GPS coordinates like **42.1234** per **22.1234** and merge them as a string, with a separator character:

`42.1234 x 22.1234`

But using this code:

`gps_string = (String)gps.location.lat()+' x '+(String)gps.location.lng();`

I lose the last decimals and I get:

`42.12 x 22.12`

The only way I could see full coordinates is by specifying an extra parameter to println, like this:

`Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);`

How can I create a string containing both two coordinates without losing decimals ? e.g `42.1234 x 22.1234`

Comment: your question has nothing to do with GPS ... it is a question about converting a floating point number to string without losing precision

Comment: one thing to note, the GPS module probably outputs text, not floating point numbers

Comment: What GPS module have you got? What GPS library are you using?

Comment: @Dougie I can check when I get back on computer but like jsotola said, it is a float number conversion issue, not really speciffic to this GPS, but to Arduino.

Comment: Try using `dtostrf(val, 4, 6, buff);` rather than casting the value to a String.

Comment: the CStringBuilder from my StreamLib allows to build a C string (char array terminated by 0) with the same functions you use on Serial

Comment: @jsotola: The GPS module probably outputs text in the NMEA format, with degrees, minutes, and minute decimals. So you'll need to convert that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 4 decimal places, you may try something like this:

```cpp
gps_string = String(gps.location.lat(), 4)
           + " x "
           + String(gps.location.lng(), 4);
```

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=243660.0 suggests avoiding `Strings` and `String()` functions. Use `dtostrf(val, 4, 6, buff);`

Comment: This one works very nice (simple). If I can simplify the code a bit, I will post an answer using the `dtostrf`. I understand the `dtostrf` method is for memory/performance considerations.